# how to fix Windows NT user or group 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool' not found?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, iis-7.5

when I run on sql server 2005:

```
EXEC sp_grantlogin "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool"
```

I get the error:

```
Msg 15401, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_grantlogin, Line 49
Windows NT user or group 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool' not found. Check the name again.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you created a user in SQL Server for this login? There has to be a user defined to hook the login to.

Comment: @DeanOC I tried : 'CREATE USER [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool] FROM LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool]' but then I get: 'Windows NT user or group 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool' not found. Check the name again.'

Comment: I found the solution on this page!

http://serverfault.com/questions/81165/how-to-assign-permissions-to-applicationpoolidentity-account

Answer (score 9):

This work for me

```
CREATE LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPool] FROM WINDOWS;
CREATE USER MyAppPoolUser FOR LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPool];
```

Comment: This worked for me, where the top-rated answer did not. I'm on SQL Server 2008, Windows Server 2008. I suspect there is a bug in the Window, but if you enter SQL directly it works.

You don't have to have the app pool identity in the IIS_IUSRS group like the top answer suggests.

Answer (score 5):

You need to ensure that there is a Windows account called `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` on the machine. Run Computer Management on the machine,go to Local Users and Groups, and look at the properties in `IIS_IUSRS`.

If there is no account there called `IIS APPOOL\DefaultAppPool` then that is why you cannot add a login to SQL Server. You will only have this account on your SQL Server machine if you are also running IIS on that machine, as IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool is a local account.

This link http://forums.iis.net/t/1174325.aspx seems to be very similar to your problem. There are some tips on how to solve the problem, including one at the very end which looks important.

Answer (score 3):

For a lazy set up on my IIS 7.5 development box, I use `BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS` instead of the application pool identity `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool`.

As the (dynamic) app pool identity users are always members of the Group `IIS_IUSRS`, if you rename the app pool, or use a different app pool, it doesn't break the SQL permissions.

ref, Use BUILTIN\Group to Grant Access to Predefined Windows NT Groups: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216808

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message after installing SQL etc. I found out that I actually didn't have `IIS` enabled/installed in `Windows Programs and Features`.

Search `Turn Windows features on or off`

Check `IIS - Internet Information Services` is ticked

Click `OK`

Rerunning SQL script should now complete.